# Share hyperlink on twitter using socialize framework in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, socialize-sdk

I am using [Socialize](http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-ios/index.html) framework for sharing on facebook and twitter.
I am totally unaware as how to share hyperlinks on twitter using this framework. I checked out its documentation for twitter sharing thoroughly but no luck. Please shed some light on sharing hyperlink on twitter incase you have any clue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do following to share.

```
#import "Social/SLComposeViewController.h"
#import "Social/SLRequest.h"
SLComposeViewController *socialVc=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
                    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.defaultImageView.image, 1.0);
                    [socialVc addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                    [socialVc setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"hello"]];
                    [socialVc addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.xyz.com"]];
                    [self.navigationController presentViewController:socialVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Well initially i was using social framework only..but this is regarding Socialize SDK..http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-ios/sharing.html.. Check out. Here i dont knw how cn i Add hyperlink for twitter share. Thanks for help.

Comment: k. But if you want above ios 6 then you should use go for controller provided by apple.

Comment: nope thats the reason i switched to socialize as i wanted compatibility with ios 5 too.